# Fatal error: Allowed memory

Tags: wordpress, memory-management, w3-total-cache

I tried to activate W3 Total Cache wordpres plugin and got some blank screen with memory error message. After I deactivated all plugins and set the default WP theme, my front page still says :

« Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted », although my wp-config contains the line : define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '96M');

How is that possible ?

Answer (score 1):

I would not set memory limit as -1, you are asking for your host to kick you off the server.

Answer (score 0):

add this in top of wp-config

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```